# mysql database management with hierarchical structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am new to database design/management and mysql, so I need some hints to find a more efficient solution to manage a specific type of data

I have a table of items (products) that contains all the descriptive fields and each record has a unique key.

Some item (not all) can be the union of different items. Example: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5...where item3 is a combination of 1 unit of item1 and 3 units of item2.
It can be also that an item might contain a 'package of items'. Example item5 that contains 1 unit of item4 and 1 unit of item3(1 unit of item1 and 3 units of item2).

Now, I need to manage all the child items since most of the descriptive fields are included there and I need to calculate results at this level. Moreover I need to calculate the same results at the parent level.
All items (simple or packed) could be sold with an economic result linked to that specific item.

How would you structure the database? Is it possible to manage this in a single table?
It is sort of a hierarchical structure but the items properties are flexible and I could build any kind of combination of items creating a new item.

At the moment I have created a table ITEM including all the general properties of all simple and package items. Then another table (BASKET) with the relation between the package and the single child:

```
**ITEM**

key ; description ; type ; other calculated fields ;

1 ; A ; child ; ...

2 ; B ; child ; ...

3 ; C ; pack ;  ...from aggregation...

4 ; D ; child ; ...

5 ; E ; pack  ; ...from aggregation...



**BASKET**  

key_basket ;    key_child ; units ;

3 ; 1 ; 1 ; 

3 ; 2 ; 3 ; 

5 ; 3 ; 1 ; 

5 ; 4 ; 1 ;
```

Does this make sense? What would you do in this case? Is it correct? Is there a way to not duplicate information and manage all this in one table?

Comment: take care with cycles

Comment: You don't want to have everything in one table. Your structure looks acceptable enough for what you've described, and unless there's some weird stuff going on that you didn't mention, appears to be normalized enough. One recommendation would be to move the type to a separate table and have that contain an id and a string, and in your item table just have the type_id.

Comment: thank you, ... since I need to calculate analytic results for each child and then be able to aggregate the result for each combination (father), I guess I should develop a store procedure to create a new table starting from ITEM that 'substitute' the type 'pack'lines with n 'child' lines representing the father item. This because the I can group result by key and have a total result for the father. is it correct my point? I am wondering about db space usage creating a new table that could be very big and represent a duplication of information...